# No ejecuta ninguna acción al entrar en onResponse

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, async

Estoy intentando realizar un Login a una base de datos Local, después de debuguar un rato me he dado cuenta que el problema esta en que no me realiza las acciones añadidas al método onResponse, nunca entra en ese método.

LoginRequest-->

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {


    public LoginRequest(String username,String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST,LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);

        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("usuario",username);
        params.put("clave",password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String,String> getParams() {return params;}
}
```

MainActivity-->

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


    Button btn_menu;
    EditText et_username,et_password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_menu);
        et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);

        btn_menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String usuario = et_username.getText().toString();
                final String clave = et_password.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> respuesta = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) { // aqui si el login es correcto

                                //recibo con el json
                                String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                String user_id = jsonResponse.getString("user_id");
                                //paso los datos
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);

                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                intent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);

                                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                //MainActivity.this.finish();

                            } else { //Hacer un TOAST DE ESOS
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new
                                        AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                                builder.setMessage("ERROR LOGIN").
                                        setNegativeButton("Retry", null).
                                        create().
                                        show();


                            }

                            //Seguir x aqui con del tutorial.


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(usuario, clave, respuesta);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puede ser que tengas algún error al recoger las variables de username o password?
¿Te da algún tipo de error?

Comment: Si, como parece ser, quieres implementar una clase singleton para tus peticiones `Volley`, entonces haz algo bien hecho, [aquí hay un buen ejemplo de patrón singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604191/5587982). Tu código es confuso e incoherente. Por ejemplo, el tipo de respuesta que se espera es de tipo `String`, pero luego intentas manejar un `JSONObject`. Quizá hagas eso porque lo que responde el servidor no depende de ti. Si dependiese de ti, lo mejor sería responder desde el servidor un objeto JSON directamente y evitar conversiones posteriores.

Comment: no me da ningún tipo de error, solo al pulsar el boton iniciar sesion , no realiza ninguna acción de las indicadas en el onResponse.